# Responsive Website: What am I Missing?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When I shrink my viewport, my divs (labeled "Top", "Left", and "Right") stack on top of each other like I want them, but don't show their full widths. The widths of each div becomes cut, so you can't see their full width on a mobile device. How should I change my code to show the full width of each div on a mobile device?

```css
body 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper 
{
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -450px;
    top: 0;
}

#main
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 900px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #99CCCC;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -450px;
}

#main p
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

#left 
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: green;
    top: 100px;
}

#left p 
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}

#right 
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 100px;   
    right: 0;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}

#right p
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* START OF MEDIA QUERIES */

@media all and (max-width: 961px) {
    
#wrapper {
    position: relative
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
    
#main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #99CCCC;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    top: 150px;
    display: block;
}

#left p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    top: 300px;   
    right: 0;
}

#right p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Responsive website</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" user-scalable="no"/>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <p>Top</p>
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        <p>Left</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <p>Right</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Check screen shot]Please check updeted answer:

```
You have small mistake in your code, add the " ; " after you can give 
"position:relative;" in id "#wrapper" for responsive.
```

Comment: @Leo the lion this mistake have to i am not seen width:100% in the browser.